# How to import tfrecord files in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tfrecord

I have a tfrecord file and would like to import it in a pandas dataframe or numpy array.

I found tools to read tfrecords but they only work inside a tensorflow session, which is not the use case I have...

Thanks for any help I could get !

Comment: Did u get any solution

Answer (score 5):

In Colab you can type (or on your cmd without !)

```
!pip install pandas-tfrecords
```

After installation you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_tfrecords as pdtfr
pdtfr.tfrecords_to_pandas(file_paths=r'/folder/file.tfrecords')
```

Good luck!