# TF record to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tfrecord

Wondering if there is a simple way to do it in bulk?

Looking for something like pd.read_csv etc. for a file with tfrecords and then convert it to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075288/how-to-import-tfrecord-files-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Pandas-tfrecords library helps to convert pandas to tfrecords and tfrecords to pandas dataframe i.e., `pandas-tfrecords`.

Use this library by installing

```
pip install pandas-tfrecords
```

For more details on the library find [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-tfrecords/).