# reading and decoding a .tfrecord file, and saving it to .npz file or reading it in numpy/pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, parsing, tfrecord, npz-file

I'm currently working on implementing a pytorch version of [this](https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research/tree/master/learning_to_simulate) tensorflow project. They published a paper which can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.09405).

**Dataset formats and where to find them**
The datasets available are .tfrecord files, which can be downloaded with a script they provide that gets them from a storage.google-apis site.
I was able to download the files (if you don't wanna run their script you can find an example of the dataset files in [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jRLFLhvI_8sPyePkwwS6Wyh5eeLuT3xi?usp=drive_link) drive link.
there are .npz versions of SOME of the dataset [here](https://utexas.app.box.com/s/p7kfg9vb742ofl53xu9rkwdjjukcva1p) and I'd like to have all of them in that format for workflow purposes).
the .npz versions of the dataset can be loaded as dictionaries with keys "simulation_trajectory_0", "simulation_trajectory_1"..."simulation_trajectory_999". each one of these keys contains an array of shape [320,x,2] where x varies from around 100 to 2000. this makes sense, since they are simulations of trajectories of x particles, in 2 dimensions, for 320 timesteps.
**My objective**
My objective is to read these tfrecords, and ideally convert them into .npz files, which I then load in numpy and convert to torch tensors.
I'm content even with reading them with tensorflow and converting them directly into torch tensors, but since i'm working on a group project in pytorch, I'd like to handle the data preprocessing on my own and not force my colleagues to use tensorflow too.

**The problems, and what I tried**
I am very new to tensorflow, so I was not able to read the files properly. From what I was able to gather, a tfrecord file is a serialization of large datasets, made to be read through streaming methods, and not usually handled all at once. I read many questions on stackoverflow and read the TF documentation and it seems like I need to learn the features of my .tf file, create a parsing function and give the file + the parsing function to `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`.
I was able to extract the features from my .tfrecord file using this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def list_record_features(tfrecords_path):
    # Dict of extracted feature information
    features = {}
    # Iterate records
    for rec in tf.data.TFRecordDataset([str(tfrecords_path)]):
        # Get record bytes
        example_bytes = rec.numpy()
        # Parse example protobuf message
        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.ParseFromString(example_bytes)
        # Iterate example features
        for key, value in example.features.feature.items():
            # Kind of data in the feature
            kind = value.WhichOneof('kind')
            # Size of data in the feature
            size = len(getattr(value, kind).value)
            # Check if feature was seen before
            if key in features:
                # Check if values match, use None otherwise
                kind2, size2 = features[key]
                if kind != kind2:
                    kind = None
                if size != size2:
                    size = None
            # Save feature data
            features[key] = (kind, size)
    return features
```

found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562691/reading-a-tfrecord-file-where-features-that-were-used-to-encode-is-not-known)

```
features = list_record_features("valid.tfrecord")
features
```

gives me this output:
{'key': ('int64_list', 1), 'particle_type': ('bytes_list', 1)}

And now if I write a decode function and give it to TFRecordDataset

```
def decode_fn(record_bytes):
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(
      # Data
      record_bytes,

      # Schema
      {"x": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.train.Int64List),
       "y": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.train.BytesList)} #these two types give error
  )

for batch in tf.data.TFRecordDataset("valid.tfrecord").map(decode_fn):
  print("x = {x:.4f},  y = {y:.4f}".format(**batch))
```

I don't understand what to put after `dtype=`, and I don't know how I would then go about getting the data into a proper format that I can save to .npz.

the only thing remotely similar to what need is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075288/how-to-import-tfrecord-files-in-a-pandas-dataframe), but that just gives me this sort of table when i run it
key     particle_type   position    step_context
0   0   ...     [b'\xe6\x1fB?\xa1\x12\xa8>\x19\xd6>?\xdcr\xa9>...   [b'\x00\x00\xc0\x7f', , , , , ...
1   1   ...     [b'\x1d\x8a>?\x0b\xb8s>F\xd3>?\xa0T\x80>\x8f\x...   [b'\x00\x00\xc0\x7f', , , , , ...
2   2   ...     [b'\x02s\xb7>\x11y\x8e>f\xdf\xb0>J\xd9\x8f>\xa...   [b'\x00\x00\xc0\x7f', , , , , ...
3   3   ...     [b']\x02\xfa>\xc9\x97\x93>\xc2n\xf3>\x02\xf8\x...   [b'\x00\x00\xc0\x7f', , , , , ...
4   4   ...     [b'\xd3q:?\x80\xb6\x98>\x05(7?\xb8\x16\x9a>\xa...   [b'\x00\x00\xc0\x7f', , , , , ...
...

I'm sorry for the long question but this is my first ask and I wanted to make sure there was all the info needed. Any help or ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `dtype` argument of [`tf.io.FixedLenFeature`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenFeature) used in [`tf.io.parse_single_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_example) calls should be a type from [`tf.dtypes`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes#other-members), not a python type from `tf.train`. Try something like (note you'll want the dictionary keys to match the string names printed from `list_record_features`):

```py
tf.io.parse_single_example(
      record_bytes,
      {"key": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
       "particle_type": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string)})
```